# how to print pdf pages with differnt multiples

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, printing

I have a big pdf (100s pages), I want to give the order to print the pages in different multiples
for example:

- page 1 x 1
- page 2 x 7
- page 3 x 23
- page 4 x 1

I'd like to give the order at one time instead of doing it for every page, and have four pages of the pdf per sheet

I wonder if I can give the order from an excell sheet or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely print it from a macro, and either build in the number of each page, or draw that from a "form" (set of cells, one for each page, or in the macro assume once for each page if not in the list and however many times indicated for those in the list). I MAY have the ability to write such a macro, but a bigger chance is I'd mess it up and need a few hours of tuning. I wager someone here can write a quick one for you though.

However, there is an easier way than a macro. If you use Adobe Acrobat (or that horrid online subscription they sell now), you can enter any numeric-based string of the `1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,etc.` style and it will dutifully print exactly that for you. You can mix in some single pages, so if you want 1 of page 1, 7 of page 2, and 1 each of pages 3-44, you could enter `1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3-44` for the pages to print. *(It will take them out of order as well... `2,2,2,29,1,2,2,2,3-28,30-44` would print exactly those pages in exactly that order.)*

How does that help? Well, one thing Excel can do very nicely, and easily, is build strings — if you can adequately characterize what needs to be in the strings. (Though that seems not a problem in this case!) So if you created an input range ("form"), perhaps pages listed in column A and how many times listed in column B, an Excel formula would easily be able to put the contents together in a string like the above ones.

Then just copy that formula cell and paste into the print dialogue in Acrobat and you're ready to click `Print`.

And to make an easy macro, do that and have the macro read that result into a variable that it passes to Acrobat to print the PDF.

Of course, "mileage varies" when it comes to PDF programs. Acrobat would be hard to get if you don't have it already, though the subscription version would be easy to get (more problematic would be the monthly payments...). My ten year old memory of their "DC" program says it had the same kind of print capability, but even if it is correct, it may have changed over the years.

Non-Adobe PDF programs are quite possibly all over the map on that. Lots of programs no longer accept anything except a single range (so 3-12, but not 3,5-12) and it seems likely, as some of these PDF programs flash up in the pan, but don't fire the gun long, yet there are always a dozen or two easily found in searches, that lots are fairly recently written and maybe taking "modules" so-to-speak, for basic functionality like printing and so beholden to the current trend.

Only you can tell though, by giving it a quick try. Excel can provide an easy input scheme for how many of each to print, and then easily output the string needed for you to either use with copy and paste, or via a macro. It'd be trickier to achieve if you want the pages out of order, as that would be more complicated to set up so that easy typing still magically got what you intended, but it wouldn't be a nightmare. (Unless you go crazy with what you require, I guess.)

But even if you wrote a simple "chunk-chunk-chunk" macro that looked at the number of times to print page 1 and issued the print command with that many copies indicated, or even issued a one page print command that many times, then moved on to page 2's entry, then page 3's entry, and so on, so perhaps issuing 500, 600, 1,000 separate "print this one page one time" commands, it would still get the job done. And "elegance" of programming is overrated when it comes to getting the job done leading to your next raise or promotion.